# Putting elements on a horizontal row and spacing issues using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I am tying to get all four images on one row, with equal space and to resize for different screen sizes. I am missing something but I do not know what is causing the extra space between image 2 & 3. Also I think I almost have the re-sizing down but may still be missing something.

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Connect With Us</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      
    <body>
    <div class="container">
    
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-4">
         
            <a href="https://www.yelp.com/biz/hart-marketing-and-business-development-san-diego" target="_blank">
              <img src="https://image.ibb.co/gyegWR/Yelp_Button.jpg" alt="Yelp Button" border= 0; margin= 0; display= block; style="width:100%;">
             
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-4">
          
            <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?app=110&url=https%3A%2F%2Ftest.com%2F" target="_blank">
             <img src="https://image.ibb.co/fOhPkm/Google_1_button.png" alt="Google 1 button" border= 0; margin= 0; display= block; style="width:80%;">
            
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-4">
          
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/18274166/"target="_blank">
            <img class="three" src="https://image.ibb.co/d6G6y6/Linkedin_Button_New.jpg" alt="Linkedin_Button_New" border= 0; margin= 0; display= block; style="width:50%;">
             
            </a>
             </div>
         <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-4">
          
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/HartMarketingandBusinessDevelopment/"target="_blank">
            <img src="https://image.ibb.co/n6rTVm/facebook_button_oval.jpg" alt="facebook_button_oval" border= 0; margin= 0; display= block; style="width:65%;">
            
            </a>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    
    
    </body>
```

Comment: You want all the images on a row or you want just a couple of them on a row? Do you have some relevant CSS or is it all inline?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your images all have different percentage-based `width` attributes. These are applied to the images themselves, rather than their respective containers.

For example, your Google Plus image has a `width` of `80%`. As such, there is 20% of the container on the right-hand side of the image (making it appear as though there is a bigger gap between the images).

To resolve this, simply make the Google Plus image take up `100%` of the width instead. You're also specifying widths of `65%` and `50%` for LinkedIn and Facebook respectively, and should also make these `100%` as well:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Connect With Us</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-4">
          <a href="https://www.yelp.com/biz/hart-marketing-and-business-development-san-diego" target="_blank">
            <img src="https://image.ibb.co/gyegWR/Yelp_Button.jpg" alt="Yelp Button" border=0 ; margin=0 ; display=b lock; style="width:100%;">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-4">
          <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?app=110&url=https%3A%2F%2Ftest.com%2F" target="_blank">
            <img src="https://image.ibb.co/fOhPkm/Google_1_button.png" alt="Google 1 button" border=0 ; margin=0 ; display=b lock; style="width:100%;">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-4">

          <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/18274166/" target="_blank">
            <img class="three" src="https://image.ibb.co/d6G6y6/Linkedin_Button_New.jpg" alt="Linkedin_Button_New" border=0 ; margin=0 ; display=b lock; style="width:100%;">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-4">
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/HartMarketingandBusinessDevelopment/" target="_blank">
            <img src="https://image.ibb.co/n6rTVm/facebook_button_oval.jpg" alt="facebook_button_oval" border=0 ; margin=0 ; display=b lock; style="width:100%;">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Note that although the images now all have perfectly equal spacing, they're of differing heights.

To resolve this, you could manually specify a `height` as well (stretching the image), or make use of padding between the elements.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you, so it seams like if I resize my images to the same heights prior to rendering them here then I should get the similar spacing with similar heights?

Comment: If all of your images are uploaded at the same height, then they will be rendered as the same height with equal padding. The problem is that without images with the same dimensions, you **have** to settle for either image stretching or additional whitespace :)